Как правильно конвертировать html в rtf для Adobe Indesign на C#
В общем есть программа Adobe Indesign, есть C# под рукой. У меня цель такая, чтобы я мог какие-нибудь html блоки вставлять в Adobe Indesign. Когда я вставляю просто файл .html то у меня вставляется просто код оттуда в эту программу. Я пробовал разные форматы что могут восприниматься этой прогой и нашёл только .icml и .rtf. Хорошо себя показал именно .rtf.
Но есть одна проблема, в rtf всё правильно генерируется и отображается, но когда я этот rtf вставляю в прогу, то если страница свёрстана на табличных тегах(table, tr, td) то в принципе всё хорошо работает, но некоторые стили по дороге туда теряются: цвет границ(border), отступы(не все, но половина), шрифты(бывает что шрифт не принимается и в проге отображается такой текст просто светло-красным) и тд.
Может кто такое уже делал и у вас правильно вставлялось или вообще другой формат конвертирования использовать? В C# я использовал библиотеку от Саутина прям по документации и он правильно сохраняет со всеми стилями, но опять же Adobe Indesign как будто просто не хочет принимать половину стилей.
Я пробовал pdf, он сохраняет что нужно, но не даёт доступа к редактированию, поэтому его не советовать.
C#:
string inputFile = @"C:\Users\oneta\Documents\sharp\TestClipboard\TestClipboard\index.html";
 string outputFile = Path.ChangeExtension(inputFile, "2.rtf");


 HtmlConvertOptions opt = new HtmlConvertOptions();
 opt.OutputFormat = HtmlToRtf.OutputFormat.Rtf;
 opt.Encoding = Encoding.utf8;

 HtmlToRtf h = new HtmlToRtf();
 opt.BaseURL = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetFullPath(inputFile));

 using (FileStream htmlStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open))
 {
     using (MemoryStream rtfStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
         if (h.Convert(htmlStream, rtfStream, opt))
         {
             File.WriteAllBytes(outputFile, rtfStream.ToArray());
             System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(outputFile) { UseShellExecute = true });
         }
     }
 }

 if (File.Exists(outputFile))
 {
     System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection replacementList = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
     replacementList.Add(outputFile);
     Clipboard.SetFileDropList(replacementList);
     MessageBox.Show("Блок успешно преобразован в RTF и сохранен.");
 }
 else
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при преобразовании блока в RTF.");
 }

И сама вёрстка:
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .first-block, .third-block, .second-block{
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
            -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            -ms-flex-direction: row;
                    flex-direction: row;
            -webkit-box-pack: justify;
            -ms-flex-pack: justify;
                    justify-content: space-between;
            width: 380px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }

        .second-block{
            border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
        }

        .first-block{
            background-color: #30B5BF;
        }

        .first-block a{
            color: white;
        }

        table{
            border-top: 2px solid black;
            border-bottom: 2px solid black;
            width: 400px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h3{
            color: #4B4B4B;
        }

        th, td{
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .main-block{
            border: 2px solid orange;
            width: 400px;
        }

        .main-block b:nth-child(2), .main-block b:nth-child(3){
            border-left: 2px solid orange;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

        b{
            width: 100px;
            height: 30px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            border-left: 2px solid orange;
        }

        .text-unit{
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
            -webkit-box-direction: normal;
                -ms-flex-direction: row;
                    flex-direction: row;
            -webkit-box-pack: justify;
                -ms-flex-pack: justify;
                    justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .collapse, .island{
            border-top: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
        }

        .island{
            padding: 5px 15px;
            margin: 50px;
            border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        label, span{
            color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
        }

        .island h3{
            font-weight: 600;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="first-block" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <span>Название продукта</span>
        <a href="#">Смотреть на сайте</a>
    </div>

    <img src="medeor.jpg" alt="диван">

     <h3>Название заголовка продукта</h3>

   <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Ширина</th>
        <th>Длина</th>
        <th>Высота</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>745мм</td>
        <td>2000мм</td>
        <td>885мм</td>
    </tr>
</table>```

